# Reading a particular line of a text file in an array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read specific lines from a text file in an array (e.g. line 16,25,34, and so on). Could you please let me know if it is possible and how that could be done?

Thanks in advance,
Pouya

Comment: And I want to start reading the text file from line 16...

Comment: What means _read specific line from file in array_? Do you want to read from a file or from/into an array? You could use `File.ReadAllLines` and access the array at the given indexes.

Comment: Have you read the file into an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a specific line from a text file in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708368/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vb)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Since this is not a code based will elaborate how to achieve that. This will depends on the size of your target file. If the size in not to large for your PC's memory then you can read the whole textfile while reading keep the count.

Then start when the file has been read to end to go through your lines using regex.

Check:

[VB.NET Read Certain text in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897204/vb-net-read-certain-text-in-a-text-file)

your solution is here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/56497-go-to-a-particular-line-in-a-text-file-using-vbnet/

[How to read a specific line from a text file in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708368/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vb)

Ok, here's I've also quoted the code to help you from the second last like I provided above. I'm sure you know how to get data from an Array so instead of `line` you will add your array.

```
Public Function
  ReadSpecifiedLine(ByVal line As
  Integer) As String
 'create a variable to
 hold the contents of the file

 Dim contents As String = String.Empty
 'create a variable to
 hold our line contents

 Dim lineText As String =
 String.Empty
 ' always use a
 try...catch to deal
 ' with any exceptions
 that may occur
 Try

 'Using lineByLine As New IO.StreamReader(_fileName)

 Dim lineCount As Integer = 0
 While Not lineByLine.EndOfStream
 lineByLine.ReadLine ()
 If lineCount = line Then 
  ' you can replace the line variable above or use the And Or to match the lines from your array.
 lineText = lineByLine.ReadLine()
 End If

 lineCount += 1
 End While
 End Using

 Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
 lineText = String.Empty

 _returnMessage = ex.Message
 Catch ex As Exception

  ' deal with any errors
 _returnMessage = ex.Message
 End Try
 Return lineText
 End Function
```

Hope this helps you.(Sorry having some problems in code formatting it some part maybe not formeted, or visible. If End Function is not visible please refer to the link. I've tried so many times to formet this but it not properly formeted, I'm using a Mobile phone.)